# How to change fill color of SVG on click when it's used as a background image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/EChLK

So unique problem here, not sure how to target and change the fill color of my SVG when it's used as a [background image](http://leongaban.com/_codepen/svg/ico_my_phone.svg). In my case here swapping the class myGreen to myGray on click.

html

```
<div id="icon_phone">Phone</div>
```

CSS

```
#icon_phone {
    padding-left: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: Arial;
    background: url('http://leongaban.com/_codepen/svg/ico_my_phone.svg') no-repeat;
    background-size:10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

current jQuery

```
$("#icon_phone").unbind('click').bind('click', function () {
    //$(this).css('background', 'none');
});
```

The SVG code created by Illustrator

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 width="15px" height="28px" viewBox="0 0 15 28" enable-background="new 0 0 15 28" xml:space="preserve">

 <style type="text/css" >
  <![CDATA[

    path.myGreen {
       fill: #39B54A;
    }
    path.myGray {
        fill: #e2e2e2;
    }

  ]]>
</style>

<path class="myGreen" d="M12.861,0H2.144C0.965,0,0,1.03,0,2.287v22.556c0,1.259,0.965,2.287,2.144,2.287h10.717
c1.179,0,2.144-1.029,2.144-2.287V2.287C15.005,1.03,14.04,0,12.861,0z M5.721,2.137h3.572c0.236,0,0.305,0.537,0.305,0.79
c0,0.253-0.069,0.639-0.305,0.639H5.721c-0.236,0-0.206-0.386-0.206-0.639C5.515,2.675,5.485,2.137,5.721,2.137z M7.52,26.16
c-0.711,0-1.287-0.614-1.287-1.373c0-0.758,0.576-1.373,1.287-1.373c0.711,0,1.287,0.615,1.287,1.373
C8.808,25.546,8.231,26.16,7.52,26.16z M13.578,22.139H1.434V4.995h12.144V22.139z"/>
```

I found out how to add classes into the svg file here:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-and-css.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a grey background image file and onclick change the background URL to point to the alternate image.

[Images cannot be manipulated by the host document. Think of SVG when used as an image as being like a scalable bitmap.](http://longsonr.wordpress.com/2013/10/23/restrictions-on-svg-used-as-an-image/)

Comment: Ah thanks exact answer... I'm building a web mobile app to keeping down the number of files and requests are crucial. I found some other solutions to changing the SVG's fill color here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978995/how-to-change-color-of-svg-image-using-css-jquery-svg-image-replacement?codekitCB=404756038.416562 and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638431/modify-a-svg-file-using-jquery?lq=1 However I will have to use the SVG inside of an img tag inside of as a background image.

Comment: image tags have the same restrictions as background images. You'd need an `<iframe>` or `<object>` tag if you want to manipulate the data directly. What these workarounds are doing is loading/cloning the image data file directly into the document and manipulating it there.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to do it in the browser try :

```
var green = '3CB54A';
var red = 'ED1F24';
var svg = '<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"  width="320px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 320 100" enable-background="new 0 0 320 100" xml:space="preserve"> <polygon class="mystar" fill="#'+green+'" points="134.973,14.204 143.295,31.066 161.903,33.77 148.438,46.896 151.617,65.43 134.973,56.679 118.329,65.43 121.507,46.896 108.042,33.77 126.65,31.066 "/><circle class="mycircle" fill="#'+red+'" cx="202.028" cy="58.342" r="12.26"/></svg>';      
var encoded = window.btoa(svg);
document.body.style.background = "url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,"+encoded+")";
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/k0cx2b04/2/)