# External CSS file doesn't have the effect on external SVG file in HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, svg

I have svg file that generate country map - named as countryMap.svg

I imported this file to html page as

`<embed src="countryMap.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></embed>` .

Now I have CSS file for styling on svg data. So I directly imported the css file to svg file as

`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="countryMap.css" ?>`

But I want this css file to place on html page as

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="countryMap.css">`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Country</title>
  </head>
       
  <body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="countryMap.css">
         <div>
            <embed src="countryMap.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></embed>
            <!-- <object src="countryMap.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object> -->
            <!-- <iframe src="countryMap.svg"></iframe> -->
         </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But Now the CSS doesn't effect on the SVG file.

For the javascript file to import, I checked here [SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638431/modify-a-svg-file-using-jquery)
But the errors are following -

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined   in jquery.svg.js 1394 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'cssText' of null   in jquery-1.11.1.js 7672
```

How can I comeout from here ???  Is there any way for the css and svg file link to html page !!!

Comment: Have you included the jquery library in countryMap.svg ?

Comment: yes.
    <script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="jquery-1.11.1.js" />
     <script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="jquery.svg.js" /> 

this way

Comment: Even I want all this plugin to add in html page.

Comment: use something like <script src="http ://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>, I have the url for jquery1.7.1 you can get the CDN url for 1.11 by searching it on google